# Any way we can authenticate the client(requesting) device with request in on App server?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, web, server, client

I am looking for a way using which an incoming request to server can authenticate the requesting device on the app server. Like we can keep some information stored on the app server which uniquely identifies the requesting client and then authenticate them before serving any page.

I have few thoughts but nothing clear in my mind.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot trust *anything* about an incoming HTTP request unless you ask for authentication information explicitly.